# array.min() <= array[0] --> return false

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sorting, datetime

As described in the title. The value in question is `min` of `red`. `ath` returns the expected result for both `min` and `max`. The elements are `datetime.date`. I did some experiments to explain this situation but it becomes even more confusing. This almost sounds fake, so I attached the screenshot of the notebook.

```
[In]
(red.shipped_date.values.min(), red.shipped_date.values.max())
(ath.created_date.values.min(), ath.created_date.values.max())
[Out]
(datetime.date(2021, 1, 10), datetime.date(2021, 7, 6))
(datetime.date(2016, 1, 1), datetime.date(2021, 6, 23))

[In]
red.shipped_date.values.min()
[Out]
datetime.date(2021, 1, 10)

[In]
red.shipped_date.values[0]
[Out]
datetime.date(2018, 7, 25)

[In]
red.shipped_date.values.min() > red.shipped_date.values[0]
[Out]
True

[In]
(red.shipped_date.values).min() == (red.shipped_date.values)[0]
[Out]
False

[In]
# I want to see if the array only searched for the first n values and that's why? 
np.where(red.shipped_date.values == red.shipped_date.values.min())
[Out]
(array([ 21769,  22728,  22730,  64642,  64643,  71007,  71008, 140756,
        140757, 154368, 154369, 154372, 154373, 154376, 154377, 154544,
        156998, 157003, 157004, 157006, 157007, 158041, 158042, 160156,
        160157, 161450, 161451]),)

[In]
# If there is no so-called min() in the array, will it recognize the true minimum?
first_min = red.shipped_date.values[:21769]
first_min.min()
[Out]
datetime.date(2016, 1, 4)
# Yes. This output is expected.

[In]
red.shipped_date.values[0] < red.shipped_date.values.min()
[Out]
True

[In]
# If we include the so-called min(), will that still be the min()?
inc_first_min = red.shipped_date.values[:21769+1]
inc_first_min.min()
[Out]
datetime.date(2016, 1, 4)
# This is expected.

[In]
# After getting rid of all so-called min() values, what would be the min() of the array?
red.shipped_date.values[np.where(red.shipped_date.values != red.shipped_date.values.min())].min()
[Out]
datetime.date(2021, 1, 11)
```

[image: above]